# Machine learning algorithm to predict next user's destination

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

I'm searching for a way to formulate my problem as a machine learning problem.

Suppose I have a history of user's locations, and I want to predict his next location, similar to how **Google Now** does it for Home/Work locations.

The problem is that I need to somehow encode user's current location, and the space of possible locations can be different. One way to approach this is to encode *topK most frequent locations* and use them as binary features, but then the model have to be rebuilt when topK locations change.

So I was thinking is there a better way to approach such problem?

UPDATE:
Specifically, the set of locations is discrete (locations are public transport stations).

Comment: I can recommend numerous papers once I determine your problem setting and assumptions. Do you want the destination to be a known "place"; i.e., a discrete location like "home", or "work", or can it be an arbitrary physical location? How far ahead do you want to predict; seconds, minutes, hours, days, or further still? Do you the user's historical mobility data?

Comment: Thank you very much! Please see my update regarding the set of locations. As for the "ahead" prediction, I just want to predict the next location based on current time (i.e, time is one of the features).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem can be profitably solved with a Markov model; estimate the distribution of the next location by the previous $k$ places. Relevant papers include:

- Prediction in wireless networks by Markov chains
- A Comparison of First- and Second-Order HMMs in the Task of Predicting the Next Locations of Mobile Individuals
- Predicting Future Locations with Hidden Markov Models
- Learning and detecting activities from movement trajectories using the hierarchical hidden Markov model
- Growing Hidden Markov Models: An Incremental Tool for Learning and Predicting Human and Vehicle Motion **or** Incremental Learning of Statistical Motion Patterns With Growing Hidden Markov Models

If you need inspiration for extracting the places from the mobility trace, see

- Extracting places from traces of locations
- Extracting Places and Activities from GPS Traces Using Hierarchical Conditional Random Fields
- Discovering Personally Meaningful Places: An Interactive Clustering Approach
- Using GPS to Learn Significant Locations and Predict Movement Across Multiple Users
- A Clustering-Based Approach for Discovering Interesting Places in Trajectories
- Scalable Analysis of Movement Data for Extracting and Exploring Significant Places
- Identifying Meaningful Places: The Non-parametric Way
- Supervised semantic labeling of places using information extracted from sensor data
- Eigenplaces: Segmenting Space through Digital Signatures
- The Places of Our Lives: Visiting Patterns and Automatic Labeling from Longitudinal Smartphone Data

It's basically a spatio-temporal clustering problem. Let me know if you get stuck on any of the papers.

Comment: Thank you, the papers sound very interesting, I'll look into them.